# error aurelia-templating-router 1.0.1 with swap-order

Tags: aurelia

**updated aurelia-templating-router for 1.0.1**

> when I use `<router-view swap-order="with"></router/view>` An error
>   occurs

```
[app-router] TypeError: Cannot read property 'animatableElement' of undefined
```

If I remove swap-order="with" the error disappears

If I use version 1.0.0, even with `swap-order="with"`, everything works.
Someone went through this?

I could not play on GistRun, it follows content (Typescript):

```
au new myapp
```

**app.ts**

```
export class App {
  router:any;
  configureRouter(config, router) {
    this.router = router;
    config.title = 'Aurelia';
    config.map([
      { route: ['', 'home'],  name: 'home', moduleId: 'home'}
    ]);
  }
}
```

**app.html**

```
<template><router-view swap-order="with"></router-view></template>
```

**home.html**

```
<template><h1>HOME</h1></template>
```

**home.ts**

```
export class Home{}
```

That's enough to see the error.

```
au run --watch
```

Comment: Is there any chance you could create a repro of this on gist.run and then post an issue to the router repo on github?

Comment: Assuming your `</router/view>` is only a typo here and not in your code, right? It should be `</router-view>`.

Comment: Yes `</router/view>` is only a typo here and not in your code

Comment: https://gist.run/?id=883568d7c8e2add9ed393150100f4744 To create a repro you can start there

Comment: Same problem for me, any solution?

Comment: I added this issue for the aurelia router [here](https://github.com/aurelia/router/issues/458) and a GistRun demonstrating the issue [here](https://gist.run/?id=483906685f79bb97b0c35b28a9af68d8).

Answer (score 1):

This issue appears to be coming from a bug in the aurelia-templating-router.

The issue is reported here: https://github.com/aurelia/router/issues/458 and probably will be fixed soon, but for now it can be fixed by simply making the change in the aurelia-templating-router.

Currently, in the swap function in router-view.js of the aurelia-templating-router, previousView is defined inside of the work function definition like this:

```
//router-view.js

  swap(viewPortInstruction) {
    let layoutInstruction = viewPortInstruction.layoutInstruction;

    let work = () => {
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     let previousView = this.view; ////This is not being correctly set 
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      let swapStrategy;
      let viewSlot = this.viewSlot;

      swapStrategy = this.swapOrder in swapStrategies
                  ? swapStrategies[this.swapOrder]
                  : swapStrategies.after;

      swapStrategy(viewSlot, previousView, () => {
        return Promise.resolve().then(() => {
          return viewSlot.add(this.view);
        }).then(() => {
          this._notify();
        });
      });
    };
...
```

As it stands, previousView is not being set with the correct object for the Previous View and is failing to be found as it should when it is being removed.

When I changed previousView to be defined in the scope of the swap function everything seemed to work as it should and it passes all tests.

It appears that all that needs to be done is simply to move the previousView definition.

```
//router-view.js

  swap(viewPortInstruction) {
    let layoutInstruction = viewPortInstruction.layoutInstruction;
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    let previousView = this.view;  ////This is now being correctly set 
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    let work = () => {

      let swapStrategy;
      let viewSlot = this.viewSlot;

      swapStrategy = this.swapOrder in swapStrategies
                  ? swapStrategies[this.swapOrder]
                  : swapStrategies.after;

      swapStrategy(viewSlot, previousView, () => {
        return Promise.resolve().then(() => {
          return viewSlot.add(this.view);
        }).then(() => {
          this._notify();
        });
      });
    };
...
```

You can easily reproduce the error here:
https://github.com/bbarne8/AureliaSwapOrderRepro